# Newtonsoft SelectToken() on Jarray didn't work

Tags: json, json.net

I've got an weird problem I came across, I believe there's a better and more efficient way than the following description:

I have a (Newtonsoft) JArray 'ja' with two elements ja[0] and ja[1], ja prints as follows:

```
[  1465164019, "{\"date\":{\"y\":16,\"d\":5,\"m\":6},\"DataDesc\":[\"0\",[\"H\",\"M\",\"S\",\"V\",\"L\",\"CL\",\"LTC\"]],\"Data\":[[23,59,23,27,38,1,61252]]}"]
```

Both ja[0] and ja[1] show the correct values (shown as they appear in Visual Studio):

```
ja[0] = {1465164019}
ja[1] = {{"date":{"y":16,"d":5,"m":6},"trafficDataDesc":["0",["H","M","S","V","L","CL","LTC"]],"trafficData":[[23,59,23,27,38,1,61252]]}}
```

I want to get the value with the path "date.m" as follows:

```
String month = ja[1].SelectToken("date.m").ToString();
```

that though didn't work, SelectToken() returns null. However, if I access it by reparsing

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(ja[1].ToString());
String month = jo.SelectToken("date.m").ToString();
```

I get my '6'. The detour via reparsing the ToString() is not that efficient or pretty, though I couldn't get the direct version to work... how would it be done correctly?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the raw JSON rather than the JSON as visualized by Visual Studio?  Visual Studio always seems to do confusing things with string escaping.  You can see the raw JSON by doing `Debug.WriteLine(ja)` or `Console.WriteLine(ja)`.

Comment: `String month = JToken.Parse(ja[1].ToString()).SelectToken("date.m").ToString();`